# Lyx: Reference to sub-figures numbering is wrong

Tags: floats, lyx, subfloats, hebrew

I have a lyx document with a floating figure with subfloats, where referring the subfloat (e.g. should be 1a) shows up as with off-by-one numbering (e.g. shows up as 2a), and all following figure references are wrong the same way (e.g. 3, 4 rather than 2, 3).
My minimal reproduction of this issue below require both the use of subfigure and to insert some Hebrew text in the document, but I'm not sure if it's needed.

Here's the tex-only reproduction (created by @scottkosty):

```
%% LyX 2.3.0dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,hebrew,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255,latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=2cm,headsep=2cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}%
\inputencoding{cp1255}%
עברית

\selectlanguage{english}%
\inputencoding{latin9}\begin{figure}
\caption{Title}
\subfloat[Sub-title]{

\label{fig:figure-label}

Figure text}
\end{figure}

See in figure \ref{fig:figure-label}.
\end{document}
```

Here's the original Lyx:

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2cm
\topmargin 2cm
\rightmargin 2cm
\bottommargin 2cm
\headheight 2cm
\headsep 2cm
\footskip 1cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard

\lang hebrew
עברית
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Title
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Sub-title
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "fig:figure-label"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Figure text
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
See in figure 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "fig:figure-label"

\end_inset

.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Please, reduce your code to a Minimal Working Example!

Comment: @Zarko It is, I'd say. Just save it as a `.lyx` file and open it in LyX.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., now I'm even more glad that I not use LyX :-). Anyway, are all definitions for fonts, not related packages (as `amsmath`,  `mathtools`, `mhchem`, etc). really necessary?

Comment: @Zarko Perhaps not. I don't actually know how much of that is included in a standard file.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. this is indeed the default lyx header, except a minor change regarding margins which do no affect the problem if I remove. If I'd delete most of the header we may get a different behavior on different machines because of changes to defaults, no?

Comment: I can reproduce and confirm that it only happens when the Hebrew is there. Here is a .tex example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7ku5zvb05wbakv/mwe.tex?dl=0

Comment: Try `\captionsetup[figure]{position=t}` after `\usepackage{subfig}`. (Unfortunately I haven't got a TeX right now, so I cannot test this myself.)